# Python library can be found in PyPi but can't be installed by 'pip install'

Tags: python, django

I got django project code and tried to install all the requirements by 'pip install -r requiremets.txt' but somehow it doesn't work.

occurred error is below
`Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement mkl-fft==1.0.9 (from -r requirements.txt (line 14)) (from versions: 1.0.0.17, 1.0.2, 1.0.6)
No matching distribution found for mkl-fft==1.0.9 (from -r requirements.txt (line 14))`

I tried to upgrade pip but it didnt work.

I should change my question..
I just tried 'pip install mkl-fft' and it worked.. still don't know why 'pip install -r requirements.txt' doesn't work.

Comment: your python version and OS?

Comment: The latest version of `mkl-fft` on [PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/mkl-fft/) is `1.0.6`, but your requirements.txt file specifically requires `1.0.9`. You can get this from [GitHub](https://github.com/IntelPython/mkl_fft/releases/tag/v1.0.9). If the code supports `1.0.6` as well, you should change requirements.txt.

Comment: my python version is 3.6.5 and using windows.

Comment: Actually I tried changing the version in requirements.txt before, but it didn't worked neither.

Answer (score 0):

Latest version of your package mkl-fft is 1.0.6 but you tried out mkl-fft==1.0.9 
[refer this link](https://pypi.org/project/mkl-fft/)
you can change your version in  requirements.txt  file and run 'pip install -r requiremets.txt' it will works.